# Wifi not working on Ubuntu and WIndows 8 Dual Boot

Tags: wireless, 14.04, windows-8

Hey guys i recently dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop HP Pavilion G6. The dual boot works perfectly but wifi doesnt connect in Ubuntu. It connects on Windows 8 perfectly. I updated my driver through Windows 8 but still the problem persists. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide if you wish

Comment: doesnt really work. tried above link

Comment: Thanks for trying it. If you notice any errors or outdated things in the documentation, be sure to file a bug report.

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422